# Export echarts graphs without a browser

Tags: echarts

I'm looking for generating png of echarts graphs without using a browser.

I plan to execute this in my crontab.

Any ideas ? I see solutions like Nightmare.js or Selenium+headless browser but I'm not a fan of this.

Thanks !

Comment: I don't know if that's possible, since it needs/uses the `<canvas>` to draw/export.

Answer (score 0):

[node-echarts](https://github.com/suxiaoxin/node-echarts) (or, you can find something similarly) is a lib to run echarts on NodeJs. So hopefully you can use it to generate images of ECharts with crontab.